Добрый день, проблема с добавлением и изменением инлайн кнопок в чат боте телеграм
Хочу, чтобы в каждом сообщении бота была кнопка "главное меню", которая бы возвращала пользователя в ,собственно, меню с выбором действий (здесь тестирую на кнопке "список компаний"). Для этого сначала создал кнопки:
companies_list = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
companies_list.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(f'Список компаний', callback_data='companies_list'))

buy = types.InlineKeyboardButton(f'Купить', callback_data='buy')
sell = types.InlineKeyboardButton(f'Продать', callback_data='sell')

После этого создаю маркап "главное меню" и еще одну кнопку с регистрацией:
main_menu = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
reg = types.InlineKeyboardButton(f'Зарегистрировать новую компанию', callback_data='start')
main_menu.add(reg)

После этого идет обработчик callback_query_handler для кнопки "список компаний" и в конце этого обработчика 2 строки кода:
bot.edit_message_text(f'{info}', chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id)
bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.from_user.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup=main_menu)

Сначала меняю текст на info (строка, куда из базы данных собирается информация), потом меняю инлайн маркап на "главное меню". И все бы ничего - работает, но при нажатии на новоявленную кнопку ничего не происходит (обработчик для callback_data == 'start' есть), более того, если в этот маркап главного меню я начинаю добавлять ряды, то перестает меняться вообще что либо и вылазит ошибка:
Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: can't parse inline keyboard button: Can't find field "text"

Буду очень благодарен, если кто-нибудь сумеет помочь :)
